# changing detail-label when using "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Tags: swift, tableview

I´m trying to make the detail-label of a cell change to a specific text when clicking on it but I can't figure out how... I´m trying like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TestCell")!

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text! = "TEST" 
}
```

How should it be done? Sorry I´m very (very) new at this.

Comment: Only use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` inside the `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Use the method `func cellForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` to get the cell using the `indexPath` variable you get as a parameter

Comment: According to the MVC pattern update the model and reload the row or the entire table view.